# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de los elementos con la función each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero obtener el valor de las etiquetas label con la funcion each() de Jquery, pero me arroja un error que el parametro element NO es una función. Cómo puedo arreglar eso?

```js
$(".lbl-asistencia").each(function(index, element){
 console.log(element.text());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<table class="table">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>
            id_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            dni_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            nombre_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            ape_pat_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            ape_mat_alumno
        </th>
        <th>
            asistencia_alumno
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            76475156
        </td>
        <td>
            GIAN FRANCO ALEXIS
        </td>
        <td>
            POMA
        </td>
        <td>
            VIDAL
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">FALTO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia">
            <input type="text" class="txt-asistencia">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Charlas/Edit">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Details">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td>
            76475155
        </td>
        <td>
            GONZALO ALONSO
        </td>
        <td>
            GODOS
        </td>
        <td>
            VERA
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">FALTO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia">
            <input type="text" class="txt-asistencia">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Charlas/Edit">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Details">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            3
        </td>
        <td>
            76475154
        </td>
        <td>
            DRUCILA
        </td>
        <td>
            VIDAL
        </td>
        <td>
            CALDERÓN
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">ASISTIO</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia">
            <input type="text" class="txt-asistencia">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/Charlas/Edit">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Details">Details</a> |
            <a href="/Charlas/Delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad a la que debes acceder para obtener el valor de cada `label` es `textContent` y esta debe ser accedida como propiedad y no como método; quedando así:

```
$(".lbl-asistencia").each(function(index, element){
    console.log(element.textContent);
});
```

Dando como resultado:

```
"FALTO"
"FALTO"
"ASISTIO"
```

Lo anterior puedes comprobar al hacer:

```
$(".lbl-asistencia").each(function(index, element){
    console.log(element);
});
```

Y revisar la sección que dice algo como lo siguiente:

```
 tabIndex: -1,
  tagName: "LABEL",
  TEXT_NODE: 3,
  textContent: "ASISTIO",
  title: "",
  toggleAttribute: function toggleAttribute() { [native code] },
  translate: true,
  webkitMatchesSelector: function webkitMatchesSelector() { [native code] },
  webkitRequestFullScreen: function webkitRequestFullScreen() { [native code] },
  webkitRequestFullscreen: function webkitRequestFullscreen() { [native code] }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, se me olvido que en la web todos los elementos son nodos, y al ser nodos tienen la propiedad textContent, innerText, nodeValue, entre otros. :)